# Hosted endpoint for Journey Builder Entry Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I'm trying to set up a Journey Builder Entry Source component in installed packages - how do I determine what the 'hosted endpoint for your custom activity' is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A Journey Builder Entry Source (a Custom Event) requires the following resources:

1. config.json
2. index.html
3. customEvent.js

[Refer to documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-contact-decision-event.htm). The endpoint is simply the publicly accessible base URL of these files.